# Write Native Swift and (Kotlin or java) in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Its Possible to Write Native Swift and (Kotlin or java) in Xamarin forms or Use Native Libraries in side xamarin Form Solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No.....................................only C#, F# C++ supported

Comment: Since you are new to community - its a good practice when someone answer your question to accept it (check mark under the voting panel). That way he is awarded and helps others with similar issue to find faster the correct answer :)

Comment: You can use binding library in Xamarin.forms project.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot write in Kotlin or Java (or anything besides the Microsoft tech stack) **IN** the Xamarin.Forms solution. You can however do 2 other things:

1. You can use C#, F#, etc classes which are a wrapper of the native ones.

E.g. In Kotlin, you can override an Activity's onCreate method like this:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

The C# equivalent is:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

2. You can write *outside* the Xamarin.Forms solution and create a library using native code. This library can be then exported and exposed to the Xamarin environment. Basically, you will create a "bridge" of some sort between the native code and the C# code.

Overall, the idea is that you can create whatever you like natively and the expose whatever suits your need in order to use it in Xamarin. A lot of native libraries have been ported this way. One example are the former **Android support libraries**, currently named **AndroidX**. You can see the official repo, together with the bindings [here](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX).

You can read more about [Binding Objective-C libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries?tabs=windows) & [Binding Java libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/). There's a lot of documentation so if you decide to do it, you have all the info.

Comment: ther is away to use binding Library in Xamarin form Shared Project Not Native Project?